# How to make a row with list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, list, range, list-comprehension

You take 2 integers (p and b) as your input and you output a list of numbers starting from p in the range of b.

Example:

```
raw(10,4)
[10,11,13,14]
```

I have tried this:

```
def raw(p,b):
    return[p+1 for i in range(b)]
```

But i get: [11,11,11,11]

Any ideas guys???

Comment: You meant  `p + i`?

Comment: You should use `i` instead of `1`, but nevertheless here you better do not use list comprehension (and probably not even a list at all).

Comment: Nope, i meant p+1.

Comment: So `list(range(p, p + b))` then?

Comment: What about `12`?

Comment: `list(range(p, p+b))` will do, or you can simply use a `range(p, p+b)` object in case you only will read from the items.

Answer (score 1):

In your list comp. there is a variable that will be taking every value in the list, you are always adding 1, and 1 always will be 1 is a constant, it would be:

```
def raw(p,b):
    return[p+i for i in range(b)]
```